App switching panel not showing correct icon
I added the desktop entry for Pycharm using alacarte app

Now, the entry can be searched/opened via the app search and it shows the expected results, ie, correct name and icon.

But when it comes to the app-switch panel (i.e., when you press Alt+Tab or WinKey+Tab to switch between apps), it neither shows the expected icon nor the app's name.

How can I fix the issue?
Note: I'm using Ubuntu 24.04

Determine the window class of the application, and make sure the desktop recognizes that window class by specifying its window class as the value for StartupWMClass in the desktop file.
To find the window class on a Gnome Shell desktop such as standard Ubuntu,run your application, then open the looking glass (hit Alt+F2, enter lg) and find the value for your application in the list on the "Windows" tab.
Edit the .desktop file so it contains a line StartupWMClass=windowclass.you.found. This way, the desktop environment will associate the correct window with the icon.
